# Environment variables in /etc/profile not work for HBase on Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, ssh, hbase

I am trying to deploy HBase in pseudo-distributed mode on my desktop which is running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

After installation, when I am trying to start hbase-master by:

```
sudo service hbase-master start
```

it says `JAVA_HOME` not found.

But I do have my `JAVA_HOME` configured in `/etc/profile`.

I searched on google and found somebody said that `sudo service xxx start` was using the `login shell`. Don't variables in `/etc/profile` work for login shell?

I also tried to login by ssh from another computer to prove `/etc/profile` not work:

```
ssh myuser@mypc 'echo $JAVA_HOME > /tmp/tmp.log'
```

Nothing showed up after I issued the ssh command above.

I also tried to configure `JAVA_HOME` in `~/.bashrc` and `/root/.bashrc`. It didn't work neither.

But after I set `JAVA_HOME` in hbase startup script, hbase instance could be started successfully. Which means hbase is installed correctly on my desktop. So the problem must be in the environment configuration.

Could Anyone tell me what's wrong with my environment configuration? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`sudoers(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)

> By default, the env_reset option is enabled.  This causes commands to beexecuted with a new, minimal environment.  On AIX (and Linux systemswithout PAM), the environment is initialized with the contents of the/etc/environment file.
>
> As a special case, if sudo's -i option (initial login) is specified,sudoers will initialize the environment regardless of the value ofenv_reset.  The DISPLAY, PATH and TERM variables remain unchanged; HOME,MAIL, SHELL, USER, and LOGNAME are set based on the target user.  On AIX(and Linux systems without PAM), the contents of /etc/environment arealso included.

This means you should put your `JAVA_HOME` setting in `/etc/environment` or run `sudo` as `sudo -i ...`.

Comment: Could I `source /etc/profile` int `/etc/environment` so that variables  could be configured in one file, which is mush easier to manage.

Comment: @WeiboLi I afraid that you cannot do that. Try `sudo -i`. If that works and you always want `sudo -i` instead of `sudo`, you could alias `sudo` to `sudo -i`.

Comment: If I start the service by `sudo -i`, next time when my system reboots, could the service find the right environment variable and start automatically?

Comment: @WeiboLi No, it cannot. If you want your service to start automatically, you need to add it to the automatically start service list (On Debian you could use `rcconf` to add it to proper runlevel, I am not sure how to do it on Ubuntu), and add all the necessary setting to its init file.